# Writing a test for an authorize.net refund

Tags: authorize.net

Authorize.net won't ever allow you to refund a transaction that was submitted the same day. Writing a test that creates a transaction and then refunds it, therefore, is tough.

I couldn't find a way to do it through the API so:

Can I ask Authorize.net to "settle" a test transaction?

Or .. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Settlement is a batch operation that occurs once a day starting after the transaction cut-off time specified in the merchant interface.  You must wait until settlement is complete.  In the sandbox, there is no way for a developer to force settlement.

Comment: That's *horrible*. Is there any way to test a refund? At all? Other than waiting a day after you submit a normal transaction?